# Do not see Manage Assignments in Permission Sets

Tags: permissions, user, permission-sets

I can not find **Manage Assignments** in **Permission Sets**. There is just no such button.

[image]

Why would I expect the **Manage Assignments** be there? Because it is told on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/data_security/units/data_security_objects?trailmix_creator_id=00550000006yDdKAAU&trailmix_id=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-i-credential) that it is there:

> ...
>
> Use the Quick Find box to find **Permission Sets** in Setup.
>
> Click Clone next to the set you want to copy.
>
> Enter a label and a description.
>
> ...
>
> Click Save to go back to the permission set overview page.
>
> In the permission set toolbar, click **Manage Assignments**, then click **Add Assignments**.
>
> ...

What am I doing wrong here? Why don`t I see the **Manage Assignments** button?

Comment: Permission Set overview page != Permission Sets overview page. There is a step missing in a trailhead to click on newly created PS probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click on the *name* of the Permission Set you wish to assign, then click the Manage Assignments button, located on the top bar of buttons.

Comment: Lol. Thank you. I remember seeing the button somewhere. I checked the Users and Profiles for it, but with no use.